# Execute a function when it is retrieved via a String

Tags: javascript

I have the situation that I retrieve a function in a string:

```
var function_name = "function Test(value){return value + 1}";
```

now I want to execute the function and store the value inside a variable so for example:

```
var value = 10;
var calc_value = function Test(value){return value + 1}
console.log(calc_value); // should show 11
```

But I do not know how I could get the function out of the string and execute it and store the result in a variable.

Any ideas how I could do that? I know that having the function inside a string is not ideal at all but I can not change that.

Comment: Please have a look at eval(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: First of all, you can't declare function as variable. `function`is reserved word.

Comment: @RamaKrishna good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval()`. For eg:

```js
var str='function Test(value){return value + 1}';
    eval(str);
    alert(Test(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval() to evaluate the expression

```js
var str="function Test(value){return value + 1}";
eval(str);
console.log(Test(1));
```